# Prove $D(A):= \{w\in H^{2}(0, 2\pi): w(0) = w(2\pi), w^{'}(0) = w^{'}(2\pi) \}$ is dense in $L^{2}(0,2\pi).$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $H^{2}(0, 2\pi)$ and $L^{2}(0, 2\pi)$ be standard notation for the well-known functional spaces.

Prove

$$D(A):= \{w\in H^{2}(0, 2\pi): w(0) = w(2\pi), w^{'}(0) = w^{'}(2\pi) \}\; is\; dense\; in\; L^{2}(0,2\pi).$$

What I was trying is to prove that $C_{c}^{\infty}([0, 2\pi])$ is dense in $L^{2}(0, 2\pi).$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Trigonometric polynomials are dense in $L^{2}(0,2\pi)$.